# Limit the number of levels (depth) of a taxonomy vocabulary

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I would like to limit the depth of a taxonomy vocabulary to a maximum number parent/child nestings. I would like my users to not be able to add at most 4 levels deep of taxonomy terms per tree. Is there a module for this or what code is needed to enforce this depth on the tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of Googling and trial and error I came up with the following means of limiting a vocab's depth. You can make it as specific as you like:

**Limit the depth of Parents on the term edit page:**

```
function MY_MODULE_form_taxonomy_form_term_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  if ($form['#bundle'] == 'MY_VOCAB') {
    // Limit parents to none or only top level items
    foreach ($form['relations']['parent']['#options'] as $tid => $option) {
      if (substr($option, 0, 1) == '-') {
        unset($form['relations']['parent']['#options'][ $tid ]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Limit the depth of Tabledrag on the taxonomy terms listing page:**

I could not re-implement `theme_taxonomy_overview_terms()` as another module had already done this and it made no sense to do that.

```
function MY_MODULE_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  if (current_path() == 'admin/structure/taxonomy/MY_VOCAB') {
    // Prevent tabledrag from allowing more than two levels in this hierarchy
    $settings['tableDrag']['taxonomy']['term-depth'][0] = array(
      'target' => 'term-depth',
      'source' => 'term-depth',
      'relationship' => 'group',
      'action' => 'depth',
      'hidden' => false,
      'limit' => 1,
    );
    drupal_add_js($settings, 'setting');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no current way to limit a taxonomy depth using a 3rd party module that I know of. The maximum depth of taxonomies is limited by the database table structure, not just PHP code, to 9 levels in D7. You could add a custom validator on taxonomy term add/edit forms (and with extra logic certain Taxonomy Trees) to enforce a maximum parent depth. See [Custom Validation while adding a term under taxonomy](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/98576/custom-validation-while-adding-a-term-under-taxonomy)

Comment: Thanks tenken.  Does this apply to the taxonomy itself?  I'm not looking to limit what nodes can reference to, but the taxonomy itself.  I don't want users to be able to create a fourth level, for example.

Comment: Applies to UI on Nodes. Not taxonomy admin UI.

Comment: Well, per my original question: _I'm not talking about which terms a node can reference; instead I'm talking about actually limiting the number of levels a taxonomy vocabulary can contain._  Also, what I said about the Taxonomy Manager UI was secondary, a plan B in case I couldn't limit the taxonomy otherwise.

Comment: please see my edits to simplify your question and my answer.