# Is there a limit on taxonomy hierarchy depth by default?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

Is there a limit on a taxonomy hierarchy depth by default? [This question's answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/165696/limit-the-number-of-levels-depth-of-a-taxonomy-vocabulary) states that the default limit is 9 due to database table structure, but I successfully nested 10+ terms in a vocabulary locally, so that doesn't seem to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

I just posted an answer to a similar question at https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/199247/6488 but if you are wanting it to be a sitewide default you would:

1. remove the `if ($form['#bundle'] == 'MY_VOCAB')` from
   `hook_form_taxonomy_form_term_alter()`
2. Change the check against `current_path()` in the `hook_preprocess_page()`

Some clever person could turn this into a module!